# Ad hoc packaging flex application for iOS on Intellij IDEA

Tags: ios, apache-flex, air, intellij-idea, adt

I'm new to iOS AND Intellij IDEA ...

I have written a small flex application for Android and iOS. While deploing the app the my Android device for testing was pretty simple, I am stuck now on testing the app on my iOS device.

What I did so far:

- requested a development certificate (wildcard)
- added my device to the portal

as described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/YourFirstAppStoreSubmission/ProvisionYourDevicesforDevelopment/ProvisionYourDevicesforDevelopment.html).

Since I am not developing on Xcode for now, I can not follow the description any more and have to do it the Intellij-Way.

Btw. I am using Intellij IDEA 11.1.1 on a Mac (Lion).

At my IDE I've configured the iOS part for the ADT like here:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qw9tx.png)

So far, so good.

When I run the packaging process for a ad hoc package, I always get the message:

```
9:42:32 PM Compilation completed successfully
9:42:34 PM Failed to package AIR application CatalogApp.ipa:
           Unable to open mobile provisioning profile.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your provisioning profile is not correct. You need a .mobileprovision

[image: download here]

This needs to be tied to your Cert

Comment: Thank you so much! I wasn't aware that there are different types of profile.

Comment: @Randy yup, and when you go to deploy you're going to need a distribution provisioning file